# Is there a way to convert between arduino and raspberry pi pins

Tags: arduino-mega, raspberrypi

I have a robot that I have brought that is designed for raspberry pi (it comes with a raspberry pi HAT), and I am terrible at using my raspberry pi. So I was thinking what if there is some sort of way that I could use the digital pins on the arduino and the pins on the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi.

My idea is currently this (I actually have not tried it out yet just in case something goes wrong):

- Connect an arduino digital pin to the bottom of one of the female
  pins on the raspberry pi HAT (which would be typically used on a
  raspberry pi rather than an arduino)

[image]

Would this be possible?

Comment: of course it is possibke ... use dupont jumpers with male connector at one end and a female connector at the other end

Comment: The Pi is 3.3V, Depending on what is on that "hat" you may need 5V <-> 3.3V logic level conversion.

Comment: @jsotola So could it be possible to connect digital pin 10 (just a random one for example), to GPIO pin 26 on the raspberry pi HAT and then use this digital input going through GPIO pin 26 on the raspberry pi somehow to control a motor?

Comment: @Majenko That makes thing a whole lot more difficult, would is simply be just most reasonable to supply the raspberry pi HAT with 3.3V?

Comment: @DigitalRookie4 No, you're thinking backwards. The "simplest" option would be to use a 3.3V Arduino.

Comment: @Majenko So you are meaning supplying the raspberry pi HAT with 3.3V from the arduino's 3.3V pin?

Comment: No. You *either* (depending of course on what is actually on that "hat" - RTFDS...) need to convert the Arduino's 5V GPIO signals to 3.3V *or* use an Arduino that runs at 3.3V so that it already outputs 3.3V GPIO signals.